# Shared folder not visible in Win32_Share

Tags: windows, network-programming, windows-10

I have shared a folder.

When I right-click it, it says under "Sharing":

"Network path: \DESKTOP-K77052H\Users\VMWareUser\Desktop\ausgaber"

(I have attached a screenshot).

However, this folder is not listed when I query Win32_Share:

```
    Dim strComputer As String = "."
    Dim objWMIService As Object = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Dim colShares As Object = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Share where type=0")

    For Each objShare In colShares

        Debug.Print(objShare.path)
```

I do see other shared folders, but not this one.
The other ones that our output in the above code do not have special permissions, just like the folder in question, so I don't understand the difference between those and the folder that I expect to the output in the above function.

I've also restarted the computer, deleted the share, shared it again, it wouldn't help.

What might be the issue here?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found myself in similar situation when few folders were shared when I enable sharing via property dialog and few weren't.

To fix this you need to enable sharing by clicking on **Advanced Sharing...** button, see attached image below:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I do it the same way, but I would have wished for an explanation why I have to do this for some paths, and not for others.

Comment: Also, I was hoping for a way to do this share via "net share", but that is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: @tmighty I don't have any firm explaination for it (only windows dev could give that :P) but for me it happened for all public folders.